# how can i set a long string value in android eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, string

how can i set long string value in android?

```
<string name="ferrariContent1">
<i>Ferrari S.p.A. is an Italian sports car manufacturer based in Maranello. Founded by Enzo Ferrari in 1929, as Scuderia Ferrari, the company sponsored                         drivers and manufactured race cars before moving into production                        of street-legal vehicles as Ferrari S.p.A. in 1947. Fiat acquired 50% of Ferrari in 1969 and expanded its stake to 85% in 2008, which it still holds. Throughout its history, the company has been noted for its continued participation in racing, especially in Formula One, where it has had great success. Ferrari road cars are generally seen as a symbol of speed, luxury and wealth.</i>

</string>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [How to ask Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before anything, so that you can improve your question and get better and quicker help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the the `<i>` tag and % mark. You can't define italic inside localized string, you will have to set typeface for `TextView`. The % mark should be `&#x25;` Also you will have to use `formatted=false` parameter:

```
<string formatted="false" name="ferrariContent1">Ferrari S.p.A. is an Italian sports car manufacturer based in Maranello. 
    Founded by Enzo Ferrari in 1929, as Scuderia Ferrari, the company sponsored drivers and manufactured 
    race cars before moving into production of street-legal vehicles as Ferrari S.p.A. in 1947. 
    Fiat acquired 50&#37; of Ferrari in 1969 and expanded its stake to 85&#37; in 2008, 
    which it still holds. Throughout its history, the company has been noted for 
    its continued participation in racing, especially in Formula One, where it has had great success.
     Ferrari road cars are generally seen as a symbol of speed, luxury and wealth.
</string>
```

Then add this to you `TextView` `android:textStyle="italic"`